# Сравнение html страниц, удаление специальных символов.

Tags: html, java

Имеется несколько html страниц. Нужно произвести их сравнение. Я выбрал алгоритм шинглов.
Имеется 2 проблемы:

1. Канонизация текста.
   Пропарсит страничку и извлечь текст - не проблема. Проблема в удалении символов вида &#блаблабла;
2. Другие алгоритмы сравнения
   Работодатель хочет, чтобы я доказал что данный алгоритм оптимальный. Почему он такой? Есть ли другие?

**Возникли еще 2 вопроса.**

Имеется массив слов, которые надо исключить из текста.

```
public static String[] stopWords = {"это", "как", "так", "и", "в", "над", "к", "до", "не", "на", "но", "за", "то", "с", "ли", "а", "во", "от", "со", "для", "о", "же", "ну", "вы", "бы", "что", "кто", "он", "она"};
```

1. Как с помощью регулярных выражений удалить эти слова из текста? Надо учесть что удалять надо имеено предлоги и союзы, которые являются отдельными словами, а не "частями других слов".
2. Замена сдвоенных, строенных ... пробелов на один. *Проблема решена*.

Comment: >Проблема в удалении символов вида &#блаблабла;

А зачем их удалять? Их либо декодировать надо, либо оставлять как есть.

Comment: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578904/html-special-character-decoding

- Оптимальность по какому критерию? Сложно вообще говорить об оптимальности, когда выбран эвристический алгоритм.

- Если вы решаете задачу поиска дубликатов, а не, скажем, сравнения структуры (вы могли бы построить `DOM tree` и сделать `tree diff`), то можете использовать следующую презентацию как референс: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos598E/bib/Princeton.pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578904/html-special-character-decoding спасибо, но это не совсем то что нужно. мне нужно выкинуть специальные символы не из url строки а из html страницы.

Comment: Удалить их можно простенькими регекспами :) Но чем не нравится идея нормально их обрабатывать? [Например](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: Спасибо) уже поработал с этой библиотекой, но мне больше понравилась jsoup

Comment: Да я всё тонко намекаю на злючее любопытство: зачем удалять-то :) Конечно, всех тонкостей задачи я не знаю, но просто из общих соображений, если в одном тексте сделать несколько замен обычных символов на "эту хрень", то как оно скажется на результате сравнения с тем же текстом, но без замен? Sorry за оффтопик.

Comment: Их нужно удалять в процессе канонизации текста. Сравнению подвергаются только слова. В идеале надо удалить союзы и предлоги.

Comment: Что такое шинглы я знаю :) Но тогда возникают другие вопросы... Можно как-то связаться, лучше в аське/жабере, тема для меня не праздная.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался со всем почти)